# No pudo cambiar la direccion del .exe

Tags: c#, exe, build

he escrito el codigo en c# en VS Code, y he creado el .exe en la capeta predeterrminada, pero al darle copiar y pegar en otra carpeta no se ejecuta nada. Alguna solucion?

El codigo esta aqui: https://github.com/MarkelAdanez/Calculadora

Y hay 2 .exe

Uno en la carpeta predeterminada(el que funciona en bin/Debug/net6.0/calculadora.exe)

Y otro que he copiado y pegado en la carpeta principal(el que no funciona)

Comment: Debes copiar la carpeta entera para poder ejecutar en otra ubicación.

Comment: sin código no podemos ayudar, no sabemos si estas usando rutas en tu código y/o si estas usando dll's asociadas

Comment: Y no hay ninguna manera de poder compartir la aplicación compartiendo solo el .exe (sin tener que compartir toda la carpeta)

Comment: depende de las dependencias de tu exe. PEro en general, no , y por eso se utiliza un instalador...

Comment: Esto te será útil: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview y será más fácil si usas Visual Studio.